# How to start a Paragraph always in a new page?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base, libreoffice-writer

Let say I have 3 paragraphs in one page. Now if I add few new sentences in 1st Paragraph, all 2 Paragraphs below the first, will move downwards in a continuous fashion.

However I want all these 3 paragraphs will start in a new page. Let say, first Paragraph will start in page #1, second Paragraph in page #2 and third Paragraph in page #3. Now if I add new lines in the first paragraph, the other 2 paragraphs below it will stay in the same pages respectively, until the first paragraph eventually become large enough to occupy first 2 pages. When that would happen, the second paragraph will move to page #3 and third paragraph will move to page #4 i.e. all paragraph will move in a discrete fashion such that each of them will start from a new page.

Is there any way to achieve the same in `Libre-office`?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make LibreOffice insert a page break before every paragraph, you can modify the paragraph style (or the paragraph properties) accordingly.

To modify your paragraphs 1-3 as described, select them, then select menu Format -> Paragraph to open the paragraph options. Select the "Text Flow" tab and under "Breaks", select "Insert", Type "Page", Position "Before".

To modify the default paragraph style accordingly, hit F11 to open the styles list, right-click on "Default style" and select "Modify". Again, a paragraph properties window will appear, but the modifications will affect every paragraph in your document, so this approach may lead to strange results.

The best way would be to define a custom paragraph style with the Page Break set as described, and assign that style to your paragraphs 1-3.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a **[Page Break](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/swriter/guide/page_break.html?DbPAR=WRITER#bm_id3155183)** and the easiest way to insert it is **CTRL+Enter**.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not pushing my 2nd paragraph to a new page if I add this Page break at the beginning of the 2nd paragraph. Do I need to perform any other settings?

Comment: Please see the View menu - which mode do you have? Normal or [Web Layout](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/swriter/01/03120000.html)? These are the first two items on the menu. Choose [**Normal**](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-US/text/swriter/01/03130000.html)